# loggin with disqus on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, disqus

Im using rails for my app and wanna integrate it with disqus, the idea is that when users when logging into the application also do so in disqus and I haven't any idea how to do this and don't understand the documentation, any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to achieve. Consider this scenario (out of possible many others): I am already logged in into Disqus, so you'd want to automatically log me in into your app. But you'll have no knowledge of my username, email, etc. from Disqus. I'm not even sure you'd be able to detect in your app that I am logged in into Disqus.

Comment: mmmm so bad.... but I was reading the disqus's api and found this  [page](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-single-sign-on), this may can help??

Comment: Hm. Apparently using clever hacks this is made possible by Disqus (it requires paying as well). This caveat apply though: *** When user "joechill" from Gotham Globe leaves a comment, he will have a Disqus user profile created named "gothamglobe-joechill". This user also previously had an existing Disqus profile "joechill". This will not be the same profile. Later on, user has the option to explicitly merge these two profiles together.*** In other words this is not true integration, but just a way to use Disqus platform for your users.

Comment: ok this will be complicated :(... but they show many examples but not for rails... if I decide to buy it where I put that code? (don't know if I explain well)

Comment: Those examples are javascript code, so you usually put them in the layout, but you still need the Rails backend to work with that.

Comment: It's StackOverflow. It's all **about** bothering ;)

Comment: I chose buy the plugin, but now my question is where do I start? Examples are given in other languages but not in rails, and I'm new with this kind of things... can you help me to figure out?

Comment: Hire someone to help you with that if you can't do it yourself.